# Defining a background for at title that spans across the top of a padded div (like a TH in a table)?

Tags: css, background, gradient

This might seem like a straightforward question but I seem to have reached a bottleneck and can't quite figure out an alternative way.

When creating tables, it is possible to style the TH row and have a background colour (with title) that spans across the top of the table.

However, I am not sure how to achieve this with divs since the container div has padding on all sides.

Two methods I have thought of include:

1. Using relative positioning - move the title to the left, increase the width (to over 100%) and then set padding to a suitable size. Given the title size might change, this might not work for different screen widths.
2. Defining a CSS "gradient" as the background and set it to e.g. 8% from the top of one colour and white for the remaining. This is ideal as its just a CSS change but given a title can be long or short (and also accounting for different screen widths like method 1) one would have to customise it for each 'page' and screen-width.

Would be really grateful for some expert input on this as it seems like it should be straightforward but I can't think another method so far that doesn't require page-specific adjustments aplenty.

Thanks!

EDIT:  Thanks for the prompt re: code - was in a rush to post this so didn't do a proper fiddle. Apologies.

To clarify:  I do not have Tables since it is part of the main content i.e. I would like a result similar to `<table>` but actually use `<div>` instead.

There are three approaches shown in the fiddle. The first is the 'table' version, and the other two are my current "solutions" which are a bit fiddly.  Thanks to everyone for your input :)

http://jsfiddle.net/Z686X/

EDIT2[image: Example of what I would like to achieve in an image form (given containing div has padding of 20px)]

Comment: Can you post your HTML.

Comment: This feels like a `colspan` issue

Comment: It very well might be. If there's just 1 title, then all you would need to do is to set the `colspan` to be equal to the number of `<td>`s

Comment: Yes, code example please. And since you are looking for alternatives, please explain why a table isn't appropriate for this task. What's the context for the solution?

Comment: If there shall only be a background color above the "pseudo cells", you might want a box shadow. Several shadows can overlap.

Comment: using shadows is a smart work around, but would have to see existing code to impliment

Comment: @Sam Denton Agree! Without knowledge of the purpose and the layout around no senseful solution can be worked out.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your comments. Apologies for not including the JSfiddle before this but have now edited my question so hope its a lot clearer now.   A table would not work alas in this context since it is part of the main content rather than just displaying data.

Comment: Have you considered putting the header in a `<thead>` tag then you can apply different styling to it and the rest of the rows in the `<tbody>`?

Comment: @scragar thanks for your reply. sorry if its not clear but I do not/cannot use tables for this content, but I would like to style the div like a thead/th row. What are your thoughts? :)

Comment: @Flick OK, I missed that when I read your question. You're psudeo cells will need to be floated and have a defined width to ensure they line up, and you'll want to wrap each row in a div that would have a `:before` psudeo selectory that applies `clear:left` to ensure your rows don't conflict with each other.

Comment: @scragar Sorry to be cheeky and a bit dim, but would you be able to provide a code snippet for this at all? I've done a JSfiddle in my edited question to illustrate the issue, so would appreciate if your suggestion could be put into context. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another solution using negative margins: http://jsfiddle.net/WV5Hb/3/.

Essentially, the top, right, and left margins have the same negative values as the padding of the container.  To make sure that the padding is consistent throughout, I first applied a mini-reset.

HTML:

```
<div class = "container">
    <h1>Title of Div</h1>
    <p>Sample Content</p>
    <p>Sample Row 2</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container { 
    padding: 20px; 
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.container > h1 {
    margin: -20px -20px 20px -20px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @DRD! I have accepted your reply as the answer to my solution as it worked the best for me as the immediate solution :)

Answer (score 3):

The flaw in your design is in the poor placement of your 20px padding. This is actually a very simple structure to create.

There are effectively three components.

1. A container grouping your elements
2. A title in the container
3. A body of content in the container

From your description, you want the padding on the CONTENT, not everything (aka. the container).

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/zazeb/2/

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="title">Important title</h1>
  <div class="content">You want the padding on this element. Not the title</div>    
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  /* for visual */
  border: 1px solid #f00; 
}

.title {
  /* any bg color */
  background-color: #1e5799; 
  /* get rid of the default h1 margins */
  margin: 0; 
  /* account for the padding in your image */
  padding: 10px; 
  /* center it like your image */
  text-align: center; 
}

.content {
  /* add the "Padding" you want */
  padding: 20px; 
}
```

Note: If for some reason you must have the padding directly on the container element, you can do some negative margins on the title. http://jsbin.com/hoqud/1/

Comment: this is the one i would recommend you!

Comment: This container+content approach is best if you have control of the markup. Negative margins will do the trick, but in this scenario they introduce duplication. If you ever need to change the padding, you'll need to update the negative margins as well.

Comment: @niko: Although I have not marked your reply as the answer, I have however awarded the bounty to it for an example of good practice that should be followed. In my case, it was a rather urgent fix whereby legacy code meant that removing the padding from the container would have had a domino effect that would have been catastrophic to fix in a short space of time. I should have made this clearer at the time since I would not wish to encourage "poor" or 'flawed' coding (as per your language) I will however, take on board your suggestion (and @andreasbecker.de) when I build version 2.0. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I'd understood your question, I've made some test with JSFiddle:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z686X/1/)

Basically played with display and background to achieve the requested effect, but I feel I misunderstood something.

```
.test-zw {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 2px;
}

.test-gradient > h1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.5em 0;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #1e5799;
 }

.test-gradient > p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 3px;
}
```

**EDIT**

Following your comment, I've uptaded JSFiddle:

[JSFiddle Modified](http://jsfiddle.net/Z686X/2/)

Basically positioned the h1 absolutelly to top and put background to the container... Also put a 20px padding to the container as suggested.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks @ZeroWorks!  I think you understand where I am trying to achieve so appreciate your efforts. The issue I have is that the containing div (or test-zw) has a padding of 20px so the h1 effectively gets pushed away from the border. I can't think of a way to overcome this aside from using relative positioning (thereby tweaking *every* page) or using a CSS gradient, because the site is somewhat responsive as well. Hope this makes more sense :)